# how can i change the background colour of tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

It is not about the text colour, I just want to change the tk background so it will look more better.

label=Label(window,text='TMU,College library',font='75',bg=blue)

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import*
window=Tk()
window.title('hello sir,welcome to python library!')
window.geometry('500x350') 
label=Label(window,text='TMU,College library',font='75')
label.grid(column=1,row=3)
#label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

lbl=Label(window,text='Student name')
lbl.grid(column=2,row=6)
lbl=Label(window,text='Enrollment no')
lbl.grid(column=2,row=7)
lbl=Label(window,text='year/semester')
lbl.grid(column=2,row=8)
lbl=Label(window,text='course')
lbl.grid(column=2,row=9)

a1=Entry(window)
a1.grid(column=3,row=6)
a1=Entry(window)
a1.grid(column=3,row=7)
a1=Entry(window)
a1.grid(column=3,row=8)
```

nothing about error.

Comment: please format your question properly

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Just about any tkinter documentation or tutorial should be able to answer your question. What specifically is the problem?

Comment: I just want to change the bg colour but in Tkinter, I cannot do this just because when I'm trying to do that it will appear an error.

Comment: I'm designing a project of library management system for my college if you can help me on the database so, please help me on that

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
window.config(bg=SOMECOLOR(e.g:'red'))
```

or:

```
window.configure(background=SOMECOLOR(e.g:'black'))
```